# gdb: how to write my own simulator module for gdb and integrate it with Eclipse (assembly only)?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, simulator

I found good videocource on programming languages and low-level programming @ [SEPL Goethe University Frankfurt](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLddc343N7YqgmsIT8Yo9SWQSNYcRnGBcW)

But their's toolchain looks strange: [2OPM](http://sepl.cs.uni-frankfurt.de/teaching/attovm.en.html) source only, x86-64/MISP specific.

I want to make my own simple 32-bit VM in form of `DBG simulator module`, assembler, integrate it with Eclipse/GDB, and adapt this cource for this VM.

`What GitHub projects can I use as samples ?`

PS: This system must compile/run under MinGW32 -- Is I need GDB sources for my simulator compiling ?

Comment: You're asking for a how-to guide. This website is for specific questions related to programming, generally involving code.

Comment: not howto, but source samples, this it was _especially_ noted